# RTL8821CE wifi fail after upgrading from 5.15.0-60 to 5.19.0-32

Tags: wireless, kernel, realtek-wireless

running Ubuntu 22.04, all was fine until an automatic upgrade from 5.15.0-60 to 5.19.0-32.
first analysis:

```
+ nmcli device
DEVICE             TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
34:1C:F0:3F:47:21  bt        disconnected  --         
54:67:06:D7:5B:A6  bt        disconnected  --         
lo                 loopback  unmanaged     --         
+ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
+ dkms status
rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1, 5.15.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
+ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fe600000-fe60ffff
+ lsmod
+ grep rtl8821ce
+ modprobe rtl8821ce
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8821ce not found in directory /lib/modules/5.19.0-32-generic
```

Any idea what was going wrong, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dkms module didn't build for the 5.19 kernel. the device should be handled with the in-tree `rtw88` module.

Remove the package with it by

```
 sudo apt purge rtl8821ce-dkms
```

and reboot.

Also check if the in-tree driver is manually blacklisted by

```
grep rtw88_8821ce /etc/modprobe.d/*
```

Comment: cool, that works :-)

Comment: Same problem, but removing rtl8821ce-dkms is not fixing the issue with kernel 5.19.

Comment: ok, fixed - it was on blacklist `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:blacklist rtw88_8821ce`

Answer (score 0):

after kernel update to 5.19 my wifi adapter rtl8821ce got disabled

I updated kernel to 6.1.12-060112-generic

installed latest version of driver from https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce

added to blacklist rtw88_8821ce (because with this driver wifi signal is weak)

Now my wifi works well

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

Check if you have already installed version in dkms: `sudo dkms status` if you have already installed any version of rtl8821cu then remove it over `sudo dkms remove rtl8821cu/5.4.1~ppa --all`(specify exect version of your installed driver). Then:

```
git clone https://github.com/ivalnic2016/rtl8821CU.git

cd rtl8821CU/

git checkout patch

make

sudo make install
```

Reboot system. If after system reboot the network will not appear, then `sudo modprobe 8821cu` and reboot again.