# BCM4313 Wi-Fi not working after upgrade to kernel 5.19.0.32

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04, broadcom

Problem same as this one:

[RTL8821CE wifi fail after upgrading from 5.15.0-60 to 5.19.0-32](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455452/wifi-fail-after-upgrading-from-5-15-0-60-to-5-19-0-32)

```
lspci
07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
07:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

I was advised to install Broadcom drivers, which I did using

`sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer`

The driver now shows in Software & Updates but I still don't see WiFi option after reboot.

[image]

```
lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.2
       logical name: eno1
       version: 0a
       serial: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:Xx
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-32-generic firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.3 06/18/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:61404000-61404fff memory:61400000-61403fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:61500000-61503fff
```

What do I do now?

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Broadcom 802.11b/g/n WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [103c:1795]
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

```
dkms status
bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.15.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 added the output as advised

Comment: OK, now please add output of `dkms status`. We are almost there to fix.

Comment: @Pilot6 Added the output of `dkms status`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)` requires `b43` kernel module with `firmware-b43-installer`.

You have a wrong driver installed that blacklists the correct driver.

You can either select "Do not use the device" in the GUI or run

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe b43
```

to get the device working.

Comment: Really appreciate your patience with me. Thank you so much. It works now.